# Why the params go through the function when i use junit?

Tags: json, junit

I want to test the controller of java-end,so I need a params from web which is request for the controller.But I am confused of map&json,and the params I made is cannot use.

the key code:

```
public Object updateListLoggerUser(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> params, Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
        throws IOException {
    if (params.get("statusEvents") == null) {
        model.addAttribute(ReturnMessage.STATUS, ReturnMessage.STATUS_NOT_OK);
        model.addAttribute(ReturnMessage.ERROR_CODE, ReturnMessage.ERROR_CODE_MESSAGE.ERROR_CODE_500);
        model.addAttribute(ReturnMessage.ERROR_MESSAGE, "No statusEvents parameter");
    }
    List<HOSStatusEvent> statusEvents = JSON.parseArray(JSON.toJSONString(params.get("statusEvents")),
            HOSStatusEvent.class);//I need make a params whose key is "statusEvent"
    UserSessionDto usDto = ControllerUtils.getCurrentClientAdminInfo(request);
    hourOfServiceService.generateOneDayStatusEventForUser(usDto.getUserId(), statusEvents.get(0).getShortDate(),
            statusEvents);
    try {
        hourOfServiceService.reCal(usDto.getUserId(), statusEvents.get(0).getShortDate(), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        model.addAttribute(ReturnMessage.STATUS, ReturnMessage.STATUS_NOT_OK);
        model.addAttribute(ReturnMessage.ERROR_CODE, ReturnMessage.ERROR_CODE_MESSAGE.ERROR_CODE_500);
        model.addAttribute(ReturnMessage.ERROR_MESSAGE, ReturnMessage.ERROR_CODE_MESSAGE.ERROR_MESSAGE_500);
    }
    model.addAttribute(ReturnMessage.STATUS, ReturnMessage.STATUS_OK);
    return model;
}
```

and what fields is the HOSStatusEvent model have:

```
private String userId;//"Jo"
private String devId;//"car123"
private Integer shortDate;//20160615
private Integer startTime;//1412
private Integer endTime;//1425
private Integer duration;//13
private String comments;//"some comments"
private String location;//"Hubei China"
private Integer status;//3
private Integer specialType;//1
```

My params which is incorrect:

```
statusEvent=[{'userId': 'jo','shortDate': '20160615','startTime': '1400','endTime': '1406','duration': '6','status': '3', 'comments': 'testlistupdate','location': 'sz'},{'userId': 'jo','shortDate: '20160615','startTime': '1412','endTime': '1525','duration': '13','status': '3','comments': 'testsingleupdate','location': 'Hubei China'}]
```

this is my relevant test Code(this part only show how I mock the param)：

```
        params.put("statusEvents", "[{'userId':'jo','shortDate':'20160615','startTime':'1400','endTime':'1406','duration':'6','status': '3','comments':'testlistupdate','location':'sz'},{'userId':'jo','shortDate':'20160615','startTime':'1412','endTime':'1525','duration':'13','status':'3','comments':'testsingleupdate','location':'HubeiChina'}]");
    //params.put("type", "S");
    String content = JSON.toJSONString(params);
    String contentType = "application/json";
    String charset = "utf-8";
    RequestEntity requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(content, contentType, charset);
    postMethod.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
    httpClient.getState().addCookies(cookies);
    int status = httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);
```

I test the function updateListLoggerUser() in the first block in this page with Junit.
but when i debug it ,it will print an exception while in this line:

```
List<HOSStatusEvent> statusEvents = JSON.parseArray(JSON.toJSONString(params.get("statusEvents")),
        HOSStatusEvent.class);
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. Are you asking how to mock a map? Or how to invoke the above method with JUnit? Side note: consider reading "Clean code" by Robert Martin; as there are **plenty** of changes that would improve the quality of your method. For starters: you are doing a **lot of things** in one method. If you would further slice your functionality then testing might become easier, too.

Comment: I want to mock a map, to test this controller.Thx.and I mocked one,turns out to be incorrect though..according to this line :List<HOSStatusEvent> statusEvents = JSON.parseArray(JSON.toJSONString(params.get("statusEvents")),
            HOSStatusEvent.class);

Comment: Please be **precise** about wording. You **mock** using frameworks like EasyMock or Mokito. But when this is just about providing a **map** that has certain content; sorry I still don't get your problem. What prevents you from creating an empty MAP object and simply inserting any of the test key/value pairs you need into that MAP; to then call your method under test, passing in that MAP?

Comment: hey,Jägermeister.I have add some information about how i test it.can you help me.My English is not so precise.I am sorry.